# How to only copy lines of code with specific word from perl file into new file

Tags: html, file, perl

I have a perl file with html code inside of a subroutine. I want to copy the html code into a new file but ONLY the html code, not the rest of the perl syntax. The HTML code is all inside of one subroutine and all the HTML code starts with the 'push':

```
sub getTable {    
    push @htmlBase, qq(<html>\n);
    push @htmlBase, qq(\n);
    push @htmlBase, qq(<head>\n);
    push @htmlBase, qq(<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">\n);
```

In essence, how do I ONLY copy lines that start with 'push' into a new file from my current perl file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy the subroutine into another file and add code to call that subroutine and print the two arrays. Run the new file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a unix-like OS, try using grep. Something like:

```
$ grep 'push' myfile.pl | grep -Po '(?<=qq\().*(?=\);)' >Newfile.html
```

The first grep just grabs lines with 'push' on them. The second grep turns on Perl RE mode (the -P) and only returns matching results. The query has two parts: `(?<=qq\()` matches "qq(" right before the text (but doesn't include it in the result) and (?=);) looks for the last ");" on the line.

This won't match multi-line quotes and the output will also include escapes, like the \n for newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl to grep the file:

```
perl -lne'm/push.+qq\((.+)?(\\n)\);/ && print $1' source.pl > target.html
```

For the output you've shown, this one-liner will work.

If your source script is more complex, e.g. multi-line statements and embedded variables, then you will need to write some temporary code to call `getTable`, print the contents of `@htmlBase`, then save that output to the new file.